# Xamarin Android MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application) not found

Tags: android, xamarin, zxing.net

Help,

I am using Xamarin.Android And I already install Zxing.Net.Mobile 2.4.1
Why i cant using MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application)
is there any component i have to install?
[See this SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6u6l.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your question it does not make sense

Comment: I already post the screenshot

Comment: I test 2.3.1 justnow, I do not have this issue. Did you try to delete 'bin' and 'obj' folder in this project. then rebuild it.

Comment: Thank you very much Leon, you save my day..I Just installed 2.3.1 and then all works fine..

Comment: I post above comment as an answer, please mark it as answer. It will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zxing.Net.Mobile 2.3.1, I test it, it did not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So for those who land here later, The short answer is there's an error in the ZXing.Net.Mobile project Readme. The call to ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application) should go in the main activity class for the Android project, in the OnCreate method, not in the method that instantiates the scanner object. It should follow the call to ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init(). Otherwise you will get the object reference error.

As a side note, I think you'll want to ensure that both ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms packages are installed across all your Xamarin projects. Also, version 2.4.1 appears to be based on .NET Standard, whereas the earlier versions appear to be based on .NET Framework. I found this out when I tried to downgrade as suggested in an earlier comment.